# UPDATE and JOIN to calc new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables 1) Sendouts and 2) Test Menu.

In Sendouts I have a column "ordercode" associated with each record, some of which exist in Test Menu under a column named "CCD#" as well. This is basically a list of ordercodes we perform (in Test Menu).

I want to create a query that for every record in Sendouts will check if the ordercode exists in Test Menu, if it does then put a Y in a new column on Sendouts, if it doesn't then a N.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have switched to using SQL Server (from Access) for this since the coding is easier... I have the following code and it works except for one problem:

```
UPDATE a
SET ExistsInTestMenu = CASE WHEN (a.CCD# = b.OrderCode) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM sendoutled a
JOIN TestMenu b ON a.CCD# = b.OrderCode
```

In my table I am trying to update, it is only updating the first record for each ordercode (sometimes...) with a Y or N, the rest stay null, so there is something in this code where it doesn't continue through all the instances...

EDIT 2:
Oh I get it now, when the answer is N, it stops at the first record it finds with that order code, when the answer is Y, it will cycle through all the records with that order code, so it must be something in the CASE WHEN ... END logic?

Comment: Updated with code I cam up with, but gives syntax error.

Comment: Changed to SQL Server, code is close but not quite there.

Comment: EDIT 2 has the main question now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to join TestMenu to Sendouts when they have the same ordercode. That way, you'll get a row for every row in Sendouts, and either additional information or null, depending on whether there's a corresponding record in TestMenu.

Then, you can put that inside an update query, where you update your extra column to something like `[IIF][2](TestMenu.ID IS NULL, 'N', 'Y')`, where `ID` represents any column in TestMenu that is populated in every row thereof.

If you want more detailed help with your code, I recommend that you try something, see how far you get, and then come back here with a new question with sample code in it to get help if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a simple join. This code should work (untested):

```
select s.*,
       case when t.ID is null then 'N' else 'Y' end IsCodeExists        
from Sendouts s
left join TestMenu t on s.OrderCode = t.OrderCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the syntax up a bit for Access, but here's how you would do it in MS Sql Server:

You'll need to add an extra column to the SendOuts table. I named it 'ExistsinTestMenu' here.

```
UPDATE a
SET ExistsInTestMenu = CASE WHEN (a.Ordercodes = b.Ordercodes) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM SendOuts a
JOIN TestMenu b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: CASE WHEN not supported in Access, I guess you have to use SELECT or IIF, so I'll work on trying to convert what you are doing, thanks.